# I want tab to insert a tab in Sublime Text but it activates the autocomplete

Tags: ide, sublimetext, sublimetext3, keymaps

I am using `Sublime CodeIntel` which I like for the `autocomplete`, however it pops up and inserts words while I am trying to insert tabs. I want tab to always insert a tab unless the character before my cursor is a letter.

I reckon this could be done with a user `keymap` for the tab key to look at context, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work. You may need to play with the order of the key bindings. Add the following to your user key bindings

```
 {
    "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t" }, "context": [
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "[^a-zA-Z]$", "match_all": true }
    ]
 }
```

Note that I don't have SublimeCodeIntel installed, so unsure how it will behave with that.

As a nice debugging tip, enter `sublime.log_commands(True)` into the ST console to see what command is being executed for a particular key binding. May be useful in confirming that the command is running as you expect.

Comment: Thanks! This works, I just modified the regex slightly.
`{ "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\s$", "match_all": true }`

Answer (score 0):

A quick work around would be using Autohotkey if you are on windows.
you can assign any keys to 4 spaces like below

```
`::
Send {Space 4} ; when pressed ` enters four times Space bar
Return
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. My tab key works fine except when the autocomplete appears when I actually wanted to type a tab. I need the tab key to be "clever" and know when it's appropriate to show the autocomplete and when it's not. This could be determined by context. Either I am busy typing a word (should show autocomplete) or I am not (should type a tab).

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Overrides tab key to function as **indent key** and **insert tab char** only

Preferences > Key Bindings

```
[
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"} },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "reindent", "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "indent", "context":
        [
            { "key": "text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\n" }
        ]
    },
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "next_field", "context":
        [
            { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ]
    }
]
```